# Limit of a rational complex function using polar method

Tags: complex-analysis

I've been trying to find the limit using the polar method. 
$$\lim_{z\rightarrow 1-i}\frac{|z|^2-z-\bar{z}}{z-\bar{z}+2i}$$
So I set $z = 1 - i +re^{i\theta}$. The problem seems to be the conjugate of this expression. I believe that the conjugate of $z$ is $1+i + re^{-i\theta}$, but it doesn't yield the result of $i$, that is supposed to be the answer; however if I set the conjugate of $z$ as $i - 1 + re^{-i\theta}$ I do get the correct result. In doing so I set |z|^2 equal to z×conj(z). What is the correct conjugate of $1 - i + re^{i\theta}$ when attempting to calculate the limit using the polar method?

Comment: Maybe you should show your attempt in the OP so we might help you spot the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

$z = 1 - i +re^{i\theta}$ and $\bar{z} = 1 + i +re^{-i\theta}$

Substitute in the expression $$\lim_{r\rightarrow 0}\frac{(1 - i +re^{i\theta})(1 + i +re^{-i\theta})-(1 - i +re^{i\theta})-(1 + i +re^{-i\theta})}{1-i+re^{i\theta}-1+i-re^{-i\theta}-2i} \\ \\ =\lim_{r\rightarrow 0}\frac{ir(e^{i\theta}-e^{-i\theta})+r^2}{r(e^{i\theta}-e^{-i\theta})}=i$$

Comment: Thanks. I can see where I went wrong.